# Compute multiple new columns by name pattern in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, multiple-columns

I have data with population numbers, births and deaths by year and country, disaggregated by gender and age. I would like to compute the net migration rate for each year-country-gender-age combo. Here is what the data looks like:

[image: data]

The formula to compute the net migration rate (following the naming convention of the data) would be: 2001_netmigration = 2001_pop - 2000_deaths + 2000_births - 2000_pop . I want to perform this for all years from 2001 to 2020., i.e. over all columns.

I tried the following code:

```
n <- 2001

while(n <= 2020){
  aux  <- aux %>% 
    mutate(., paste0(n,"_netmigr") = paste0(n,"_pop") - paste0((n-1),"_deaths") + 
             paste0((n-1),"_births") - paste0((n-1),"_pop"), .after = paste0(n,"_pop"))
}
```

When I manually run the code inside the while loop using actual names instead of the paste0 commands, it works exactly as I want it to. Is there a way to iteratively specify/identify names that I am not seeing?

Thankful for any insights!

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html. You cannot do `paste0(..) = ...` in base or dplyr (though `paste0(..) := ..` can be done in `data.table`). But doing `paste0(n,"_pop") + ...` is going to break in all cases (base, dplyr, data.table), since you're trying to add *strings*. The classic discussion used to include the use of `get(.)` or `aux[[ paste0(..) ]]`, but those are deprecated now (and have always been at least a little discouraged) in favor of discussions in the link at the beginning of this comment.

Comment: BTW, seeing your `(n-1)`, I think pivoting this data into a longer format (e.g., `tidyr::pivot_longer`, `data.table::melt`, `reshape2::melt`) makes a lot of sense to me: it removes "data" (year) from the column names, removes the need for fancy footwork in your math, and is likely easier to work with in companion code (e.g., `ggplot2`, etc)

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped! And I will remember the thing with the image for the next post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some sample data:

```r
library(tidyr)

tb <- expand_grid(country = letters[1:5], sex = c("male", "female"))
for (yr in 2000:2020) tb[[paste0(yr, "_pop")]] <- sample(1e6, nrow(tb))
for (yr in 2000:2020) tb[[paste0(yr, "_births")]] <- sample(1e6, nrow(tb))
for (yr in 2000:2020) tb[[paste0(yr, "_deaths")]] <- sample(1e6, nrow(tb))

tb
# A tibble: 10 × 65
   country sex    `2000_pop` `2001_pop` `2002_pop` `2003_pop` `2004_pop`
   <chr>   <chr>       <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
 1 a       male       494854     125496     441605     850152     564524
 2 a       female      15675     700400     884402     722577     488377
 3 b       male       863598     430942     178898     962331     762543
 ...
```

Let's reshape:

```r
tb <- tb |> 
        pivot_longer(starts_with("20"), names_to = c("year", "var"), 
                       names_sep = "_") |> 
        pivot_wider(names_from = "var")
tb
# A tibble: 210 × 6
   country sex   year     pop births deaths
   <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>
 1 a       male  2000  494854 692068 890029
 2 a       male  2001  125496 420085 334800
 3 a       male  2002  441605 341633 816369
 4 a       male  2003  850152 310789 766912
 ...
```

Now your data is tidy, and no for loop or column name munging is required:

```r
tb$net_migr <- tb$pop - tb$deaths + tb$births
# or
tb <- tb |> mutate(net_migr = pop - deaths + births)
```

If you want to, you can now return `tb` to wide format. (But why would you want to?)