# Best way to compute on large number of pairs of data.frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two vectors, each containing names of columns in my data.frame, `data`, that is in wide form, e.g.

```
NSW_cols <- c("NSW_1", "NSW_2")   # Columns for two variables from New South Wales
AUS_cols <- c("AUS_1", "AUS_2")   # Columns for two variables from Australia
```

```
head(data)
         date       NSW_1       AUS_1        NSW_2      AUS_2
1  2000-01-01 -0.38358623 -1.78824221  0.995984590  1.0744594
2  2001-01-01 -1.95910318  2.03124252 -1.695764903  0.2605978
3  2002-01-01 -0.84170506 -0.70314433 -0.533372143 -0.3142720
4  2003-01-01  1.90354747  0.15816476 -1.372269451 -0.7496301
5  2004-01-01  0.62249393  0.50623480 -2.207919779 -0.8621983
6  2005-01-01  1.99092044 -0.81999511  1.822122519  2.0480403
```

I need to compute `share_i := NSW_i / AUS_i` (i.e. row-wise, or by `date`) for `i = 1,2`, while referencing my two name vectors above.

For example, using `data.table`, I can do something like:

```
setDT(data)

for (i in 1:2) {
    data[, paste0("share_", i) := get(NSW_cols[i]) / get(AUS_cols[i])]
}
```

This seems silly for only a few columns, but in reality my application has several thousand columns. Moreover, in my actual application, I need to do more than simply divide one column by the other. Therefore, I am trying to find a solution that will work for any function accepting two numeric vectors as inputs.

The data comes to me in a somewhat random form, so the convenient ordering of the columns in this example is also not something I can use.

**Q: What is the best way to compute on many pairs of columns using vectors of names?**

Suspicion: Maybe there is a [clever way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72490154/compute-multiple-new-columns-by-name-pattern-in-r?rq=1) to do this by converting the data to long form? I haven't been able to make it work.

---

Example data:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(10957, 11323, 11688, 12053, 
12418, 12784, 13149, 13514, 13879, 14245, 14610, 14975, 15340, 
15706, 16071, 16436, 16801, 17167, 17532, 17897), class = "Date"), 
    NSW_1 = c(1.24119982707737, 0.138858419103515, 1.71063158823657, 
    -0.430640974722993, -1.04422958092706, 0.537579524580529, 
    -0.669585987150229, 0.638805611438309, -1.72398983449257, 
    -1.74243008034091, 0.689804173282994, 0.330963177173467, 
    0.871067708948055, -2.01624558221344, 1.21257910351036, 1.20049469882194, 
    1.03206832593544, 0.786410256177216, 2.11007351377927, -1.45380984681329
    ), AUS_1 = c(-0.58310384813065, 0.409723982550305, -0.806981635414238, 
    0.0855504408545073, 0.746243168639741, -0.653673061331084, 
    0.657105983301959, 0.549909235009709, -0.806729358432671, 
    -0.997379717276235, 0.97589063842626, -0.169423180700716, 
    0.72219177943747, -0.844418606912503, 1.27729368500115, -1.34311054918022, 
    0.765340668860696, 0.464202569980373, 0.267993278040529, 
    0.667522687135242), NSW_2 = c(0.398467283863779, -0.638071030930068, 
    -0.267712904023511, 0.359879564885712, -1.31286609394071, 
    -0.883969609668706, 2.07709479458465, -2.09922563220098, 
    -1.23850596532828, 0.990433089664036, 1.08866186319808, 0.839852254188259, 
    0.0568586386833875, 0.32387805118027, -0.904668667590953, 
    -0.65218384837012, -0.262454637960949, -0.934662840905703, 
    0.821161212634175, -1.62425917345994), AUS_2 = c(-1.03040366948029, 
    -1.261929311973, 0.39218462589648, -1.13143826165372, 0.544144484008162, 
    1.17660893473457, 0.0252285692390373, 0.515133169692034, 
    -0.654109760017422, 0.503641990827566, -1.2721192223284, 
    -0.0767711536986575, -1.34531937567941, -0.266317560246187, 
    1.08756299501947, 0.700567795415207, -0.4427595146404, -0.78851996588786, 
    -0.856775709774438, -0.746419014623393)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way.
Use `lapply` not on the columns names vectors but on an index to them.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

i <- sub(".*(\\d+$)", "\\1", NSW_cols)
shares <- paste("share", i, sep = "_")

data[, (shares) := lapply(seq_along(NSW_cols), \(i) get(NSW_cols[i])/get(AUS_cols[i]))]
head(data)
#>           date      NSW_1       AUS_1       NSW_2       AUS_2    share_1      share_2
#>  1: 2000-01-01  1.2411998 -0.58310385  0.39846728 -1.03040367 -2.1286085  -0.38670988
#>  2: 2001-01-01  0.1388584  0.40972398 -0.63807103 -1.26192931  0.3389072   0.50563136
#>  3: 2002-01-01  1.7106316 -0.80698164 -0.26771290  0.39218463 -2.1197900  -0.68261958
#>  4: 2003-01-01 -0.4306410  0.08555044  0.35987956 -1.13143826 -5.0337669  -0.31807265
#>  5: 2004-01-01 -1.0442296  0.74624317 -1.31286609  0.54414448 -1.3993154  -2.41271598
#>  6: 2005-01-01  0.5375795 -0.65367306 -0.88396961  1.17660893 -0.8223982  -0.75128582
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It's a shame one can't avoid `get()` (or similar) calls while doing this kind of thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse` I'd do something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

map_dfc(
  seq_along(NSW_cols),
  ~ {
    (data[[NSW_cols[.x]]] / data[[AUS_cols[.x]]]) %>%
      list() %>%
      set_names(paste0("share_", .x))
  }
) %>%
  bind_cols(data, .)
```

---

No binding:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

mutate(
  data,
  map_dfc(
    seq_along(NSW_cols),
    ~ {
      (data[[NSW_cols[.x]]] / data[[AUS_cols[.x]]]) %>%
        list() %>%
        set_names(paste0("share_", .x))
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: I like this solution but I'm going to prefer the `data.table` solution because it avoids binding columns after the new columns have been created. Also we should be able to remove the magrittr dependency with `|>` here, although might need to reorder the columns afterwards (I don't think `_` works with `...` arguments?).

Comment: I usually go with `|>` on my projects but default to `%>%` on Stack Overflow as some people might still be <4.1.0. Anyway, (1) `set_names` is on `magrittr`, and (2), as you mentioned, `_` can only be used on named arguments. The `magrittr` dependency can be ditched by using some variables to store intermediate results.

Comment: Also, you could avoid binding the columns after creation by calling the map function from `mutate`.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include this solution but I think it's less readable.